# Python : Import cairo error (2.7 & 3.6) undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pygtk, python-3.6, pycairo

I get the following error when trying to import gtk in Python 2.7 :

`>>> import gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "gtk/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gtk import _gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index`

And I get the following error when trying to import cairo from Python 3.6:

`>>> import cairo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index`

I compiled and built the modules in the order as given in the BLFS book.
I also installed cairo as given in the book with tee enabled.

My system is an LFS, with 4.14.4 Kernel Version, with Python 2.7.14 and Python 3.6.4.

EDIT: Downloaded the source and did 'make uninstall' and then reinstalled it. Now I can import cairo without any errors.

Comment: @KarlRichter I just redid the compilation and it worked. None of the answers really worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I just shifted on older version of pycairo.  Try downloading version 1.11.0.

`pip uninstall pycairo pip install pycairo==1.11.0`

You can do shift on other versions available too.
At this time; they are:-

`1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.12.0, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.13.3, 1.13.4, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.15.5, 1.15.6, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.18.0`

I don't know much about its internals, i just used brute force to get a solution.
Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 quick and practical solution - if you have dependencies (igraph) that relies on cairo this will fix things with minimal hassle.

Comment: version 1.14.1 worked for me, 1.11.0 had some conflict

Answer (score 4):

```
conda install -c conda-forge pycairo
```

Just install your pycairo using this command, it will work fine and run fine. No need to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

install cairocffi, and
replace `import cairocffi`  with `import cairocffi as cairo`.

Comment: +1 this workaround actually works, at the cost of changing "import cairo" to "import cairocffi as cairo" in all of your code. It is weird that the official cairo package has this problem.

Comment: Where exactly do I change the line to 'import cairocffi as cairo' in the gtk library. And do I need the cairo library anymore?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using conda and I have same issue, but path are little bit different due to conda env:
`ImportError: /home/juro/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index
$ ldd /home/juro/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
$ outputs:
...
libcairo.so.2 => /home/juro/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007ff6d8ad9000)
...`

It seems that conda (anaconda) package cairo is broken or pip pycairo package is broken (I don't know who's fault it is ;)). It's missing symbol **cairo_tee_surface_index** in "libcairo.so.2" library. That symbol is required by pycairo package (pip install pycairo), so when you do "import cairo" you get that failure.

You have these options:

1. I found out that my system (debian) libcairo.2 has that missing symbol:
   `$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.8 | grep cairo_tee_surface_index`. So I just downgraded my conda's cairo to the same version as on my system `conda install cairo=version` and copied my system libcairo over my conda libcairo:`cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.8 ~/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2.11400.8`. You can backup the original one, but don't use move command (mv) because those libraries are hardlinks (those libraries can be shared among multiple conda environments). Use just cp for backup.
2. You can change RPATH inside "_cairo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so" libary file using chrpath command (man chrpath) to point to folder where is correct libcairo.so.2. With correct one I mean the library build with cairo_tee_surface_index symbol.
3. build your own cairo library (same version as in your conda '$ conda list cairo') and copy it over ~/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2.{additional_version_characters}.

Where is your system's libcairo?
`/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libcairo`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it got broken with pycairo 1.23

Please install pycairo 1.22

```
pip3 install pycairo==1.22
```

Answer (score 0):

For me,
ldd /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
showed:
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libcairo.so.2 
I had a stale self-compiled cairo installation. If you still have the original compile tree, you can run `make uninstall` within it. Otherwise, simply move the offending cairo files in /usr/local/lib manually to another location, and delete once you are sure the files are unnecessary.

Comment: ldd does not show any libraries in /usr/local/lib/ for the cairo library

Answer (score 0):

I find that the root error is not finding the `py3cairo.h`

just `locate py3cairo.h`, and `ln -s /usr/include/pycairo/py3cairo.h /usr/include/py3cairo.h`

then the compilation works without error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same solution no 1 of *Juraj Michalak* with `conda`: `undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index`, with detailed process.

```
>>> import cairo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
ImportError: /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index
```

I have the `cairo_tee_surface_index` symbol both in `cairo` (1.14.12) but not in the `libcairo` it makes use of:

```
ldd /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    libcairo.so.2 => /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f5a82de8000)
strings /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep cairo_tee_surface_index
cairo_tee_surface_index
cairo_tee_surface_index
cairo_tee_surface_index
strings /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2 | grep cairo_tee_surface_index
```

My system one is alright (1.14.8-1):

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 | grep cairo_tee_surface_index
cairo_tee_surface_index
```

So, what I have tried is to downgrade `cairo` under the `conda`environment to the version of my system (downloaded from the conda repo [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cairo/files?sort=basename&sort_order=desc&version=1.14.8) for version 1.14.8), in order to replace the default lib by the system one which has the missing symbol:

```
conda uninstall cairo
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cairo-1.14.12-h8948797_3
conda install cairo-1.14.8-0.tar.bz2
```

Then again:

```
ldd /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
    libcairo.so.2 => /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f9b163c9000)
strings /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep cairo_tee_surface_index
cairo_tee_surface_index
cairo_tee_surface_index
cairo_tee_surface_index
strings /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2 | grep cairo_tee_surface_index
```

Nothing but expected. Now I replace it with the system one:

```
cp /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2 /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2.old
cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/
strings /home/lalebarde/anaconda3/lib/libcairo.so.2 | grep cairo_tee_surface_index
cairo_tee_surface_index
```

Now, `import cairo` works !

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while installing PyGObject.

```
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dyg6e3zi/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
  ImportError: /tmp/pip-build-env-dyg6e3zi/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_svg_surface_set_document_unit
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
```

The following steps worked for me.
Firstly make sure that you are not using conda, as paths would be different for it. Then,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
```

Install these dependencies

```
sudo apt install libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libtiff-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libwebp-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libopenjp2-7-dev -y
```

Also update pip universally.

```
sudo -H pip3 install -U pip
```